# BetaFlight sees motors working, but motors not spinning

Tags: quadcopter, motor, flight-controller

I am using FlySky i6 Transmitter and a FS-iA6B receiver.

I have it set up using PPM and BetaFlight recognizes the motors in the Receiver section. All the values adjust according to the toggles and joysticks.

For some reason, though, **the motors won't turn**. I am not sure if I am missing a setting or a vital step, but this is vital for the quadcopter to fly. :)

Any thoughts? Suggestions?

**Side Note:** I have set the PPM value on the transmitter to on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this might be of help to someone with the same issue.

Everything was wired correctly, it was just the way the quad was to be armed.

**Answer:**

Hold both of the joysticks in the down position and then flip the arm toggle (SwA in my set up) to the down all at the same time.

Comment: to complete the process you should accept your answer so that the question doen't remain as unanswered

Answer (score 0):

Check in betaflight go to motors take the props off and see if you can get them to run.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Bearingdown. Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please edit your answer to explain why it is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.